# How to concatenate keys with values?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a string composed of a key followed by its value, such that the string looks something like:

> key;value,key;value,key;value

So far I have tried to use concat:

```
var originalKeyValues = entity.ChangeTracker.OriginalValues.Keys.Concat(
    entity.ChangeTracker.OriginalValues.Values).ToString();
```

...but this doesn't seem to produce what I want.

Both `Keys` and `Values` are `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string result=list.Select(w=>w.Key+";"+w.Value).Aggregate((c,n)=>c+","+n);
```

Comment: How would I modify this to handle an empty dictionary.  Split out the select from the aggregate?

Comment: If it's empty, just don't do anything: `string result=list.Count>0?list.Select(w=>w.Key+";"+w.Value).Aggregate((c,n)=>c+","+n):"";`

Answer (score 3):

I would do like this:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key", "value" }, { "key2", "value2" } };

Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(",", x.Select(d => String.Format("{0};{1}", d.Key, d.Value)))
);
```

From the dictionary select a enumerable of string then join the list by `,`.

Output: `key;value,key2;value2`

Answer (score 1):

```
var originalKeyValues = entity.ChangeTracker.OriginalValues
    .Select(OV => OV.Key + ";" + OV.Value)
    .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + "," + next));
```

I think (untested).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the ones mentioned above:

```
result = (from a in list select a.Key + ";" + a.Value).Aggregate((current, next) => current + "," + next);
```

we can also try the simple for loop without using linq :

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> a in list)
            result += a.Key + ";" + a.Value + ",";
```

Or we can use the .NET 4 feature of [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) :

```
result = String.Join(",", (from a in list select a.Key + ";" + a.Value));
```